# Tor will not start

Tags: startup

I have Windows 7 x64
I have tried:

- uninstalling and reinstalling
- running from cmd window
- stopping antivirus
- Restoring to previous version (wouldn't run though - XUL Runner "Error: platform version '52.2.0' is not compatible with minVersion >=51.1.2 maxVersion <= 51.1.2")

  -Restarting PC

  -Looking for tor.exe in Task Manager Processes to end process (not there)

Has anyone any other ideas?
Many thank for your help!

Comment: Restart into Safe Mode with Networking and try running Tor Browser from there. If it works from there, some software you've installed is interfering with Tor Browser (e.g. your antivirus or firewall, even when "stopped" this is often insufficient)

Comment: Thanks for this. Indeed it runs OK under Safe with Networking.C:\Users\Ian\Desktop\Tor Browser\Browser

Comment: But can you advise how do I work out which software is interfering with Tor? Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Not really, I don't know Windows that well. It's almost always antivirus of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it at last !!  For anyone else suffering the same problem, in my case it was simply as follows.
Problem was IBM Rapport Trusteer, which is a common endpoint security programme for online banking security.
Not necessary to uninstall it, you can stop it to use Tor then restart it to do banking, as described in the IBM help page here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS7MJT_1507/ug/t_Stopping_Rapport.html

Likewise, when restarting Trusteer, just:
From the Windows Start menu, select 
Programs > Trusteer Endpoint Protection > Start Trusteer Endpoint Protection